# Right syntax with malloc : sizeof(*int) or sizeof(int*)

Tags: c, syntax, malloc

I usually see the syntax for malloc allocation :

```
int **p = malloc(N*sizeof(int*))
```

with `p` being a pointer. I have also seen the following syntax (maybe my sources are not right) :

```
int **p = malloc(N*sizeof(*int))
```

The difference between 2 syntax above is that "star" `*` appears after the type `int` for the first and before for the second one.

Could you tell me the right syntax between the two above?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int *p = malloc(N*sizeof(int))` or `int **p = malloc(N*sizeof(int*))`?

Comment: yes, it is, `int **p = malloc(N*sizeof(int*))` I fix it in my edit

Comment: Instead of posting this question on the internet, why don't you try them in your compiler and it will tell you. Also, if you read and understand a C programming book you should be able to figure out that `*int` is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above is right for enough amount of memory. Below is correct:

```
int *p = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

or

```
int **p = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
```

In the first one, you allocate memory for integers and you return it as pointer. The second is allocating array of pointers so you need `*` character in sizeof keyword.

But for messing in future of sizes, if you change `int *p` to let's say `char *p`, it is better to use this syntax:

```
int *p = malloc(N * sizeof(*p));
```

Answer (score 4):

The second one can be used only with an *expression* as the operand of the `sizeof` operator (and `*int` is not an expression, it's a syntax error).
You probably have seen it in code that uses the canonical way to allocate a dynamic array of N members of an arbitrary type:

```
p = malloc (N * sizeof *p);
```

I deliberately do not show the declaration of the pointer type `p`, since it is not needed. Even if the type of `p` changes, you never need to touch this allocation line. It always does the right thing.

C grammar `sizeof` quirk: with an expression operand, the parentheses are optional. They are required when the operand is a type.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** The first one, *partially* (considering you have the terminating `;` in your actual code).

<del>Probably a better</del> Correct way to write it will be

```
 int *p = malloc(N*sizeof(*p));  // need memory for "int" type, not pointer to int
```

which removes the hard-coded dependency on the data type.

---

FWIW, the second one,

```
 int *p = malloc(N*sizeof(*int))
```

is an erroneous statement, syntactical error.

And, to *nitpick*, it's not a *"star"*, it's called a dereference operator.

Comment: this `int *p = malloc(N*sizeof(*int))` should be this: `int *p = malloc(N*sizeof(int))`

Comment: @tilz0R and where did I mention otherwise? :)

Comment: If you read `sizeof *p` loud, do you say "sizeof star p" or "sizeof dereferenced p"?